# Bootstrap typehead dropdown disable conditionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typehead

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/slCAiZhI3iREGBDKPqM4?p=preview) I have made a demo for my problem. Code Snippet contains angular bootstrap typehead example code. In **controller**, Its has a array that contains four values with three states and 'No result found'. And In **index.html** has a input box that populate search results suggested dropdown option. Now I want to disable this dropdown option with apply condition If the result is **'No Result Found'** . Is it possible to disable this typehead dropdown option when the result is **'No Result Found'** That means suggested dropdown option can not be clickable. Any Ideas?

**My code example:**

***HTML:***

```
<body ng-controller="TypeHeadeController">
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
  typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
  class="form-control">
</div>
```

***In controller:***

```
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'No Result Found'];
```

Comment: It might be worth your time messing around with some of the additional options on the [Bootstrap Website](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). You shouldn't have to put 'No Result Found' in that array of states since there are options for stuff like that.

Comment: Yes! I know but I need to handle this as a item of array element.